# Variable Variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to create a variable variable name in JS...

```
obj = {};
obj.fooonex = {};
obj.fooonex.start = 1;
obj.fooonex.end = 2;

a = "foo";
b = "one";
c = "x";

test = a + b + c;

alert(obj.test.start);
```

I want the result to be "1"

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mR6BH/

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561490/variable-variable-in-js/15561537#15561537

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do:

```
alert(obj[test].start);
```

Comment: @MilkMan if this solved your question, please set the answer to "accepted"

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561490/variable-variable-in-js/15561537#15561537

Answer (score -1):

generic  2 Fixes , ie a more robust solution

***goops! even  every thing as string !!!***
***From the above problem i am extending objectname ,propertyname  to be string Jang! ...***

```
objectname = "obj";
propertyname = "start";
```

// try alert(get(objectname + "." + test + "." +propertyname));

```
function get(path) {
    var next = window;

    path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]+/);

    if (path[path.length - 1] == "") {
        path.pop();
    };

    while (path.length && (next = next[path.shift()]) && typeof next === "object" && next !== null);

    return path.length ? undefined : next;
}
```

Another one

```
   function getPropertyValueByPath (obj, path)
    {
        path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]+/);

        if(path[path.length - 1] == "")
        {
            path.pop();
        };

        while(path.length && ( obj = obj[path.shift()]));

        return obj;
    }
```

Usage

```
 alert(getPropertyValueByPath(obj,test+ "." + propertyname ));
 alert(get(objectname + "." + test + "." +propertyname));
```

Non Recommented Way

```
eval(objectname + "." + test + "." +propertyname )

Another way `eval("obj." + test + ".start")`
a way of insecure and non-advised eval()
```

Comment: sorry, but... what? how is this related to the question?

Comment: sorry about that , i am agin with a new answer , how is it ?

Comment: Using eval is a bad practice. Using eval when Javascript already supports the functionality directly (through array access) is even worse. A good book to learn how to write proper Javascript is Douglas Crockford's 'Javascript: the good parts'.

The right way to access the dynamic property test in the above question is simply obj[test].

Comment: i have fixed it , look at this

Comment: @IOIOMAD awesome! Solution +1 for generic one !